# I can't fetch pages from https://vesti-ukr.com with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I can't get pages from https://vesti-ukr.com with scrapy. 
It says:

```
twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')]
```

I've tried to use any other `DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD` like "SSLv3"
but it doesn't work.

```
scrapy shell https://vesti-ukr.com/feed/1-vse-novosti
```

With any other sites I don't have issues using scrapy. And this I can scrapy this site with requests(it works good) or windows BitsTransfer, but I wanted to make it using scrapy and now I want to know why is it happens and how to fix it in future.

Comment: Just to confirm: you are using Windows? Because this works fine on Linux (I don't get any SSL errors). And which version of Scrapy and Python are you using?

Comment: It works for me too, on linux.

Comment: windows 10 home

Comment: python 3.6
scrapy 1.6

Comment: @malberts Yes with ubuntu (which I ran in winows) it's works fine, but not with windows

Comment: @ДенисИванов are you using a proxy?

Comment: @malberts no, my own ip

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your `cryptography` lib version? With `pip freeze` for example.

Downgrading version to `pip install cryptography==1.7.2` helped me to call `scrapy shell https://vesti-ukr.com/feed/1-vse-novosti` without ssl errors.

Comment: Yes, of course
INFO: Versions:
>lxml 4.1.1.0, 
>libxml2 2.9.5, 
>cssselect 1.0.3, 
>parsel 1.5.1, 
>w3lib 1.19.0, 
>Twisted 17.9.0, 
>Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], 
>pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017), 
>cryptography 2.1.4, 
>Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0

Comment: Downgrade your `cryptography` version tp 1.7.2.

Comment: @vezunckik Yes, it's work right now. But I have some window(pop-up) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p-RTFBsorX4GOUj3UnukrQSZKV3OxMmf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hm, weird. But I'd propose you to use some virtual environment (like virtualenv lib, etc), to avoid such collisions in libraries.

Comment: so how to make it? I can make some venv and install there scrapy but it will install newest version of cryptography

Comment: Yes, you're right. And then in your `venv` you will downgrade it, without touching system settings.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should to use for this site some previous version of scrapy or how to fix that error pop-up? And when scraper is working this window shows up while You don't close it and then shows up again. It don't stop scraping, only write errors periodically into console